# Filter incorrectly being applied to child relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I believe that I am having an issue with a filter incorrectly being applied to a relationship that it should not be.  Here are my objects:

```
public enum Capability 
{
Create = 1,
Edit = 2,
Delete = 3
}

public class Role
{
public virtual int TenantId {get;set;
public virtual IList<Capability> Capabilities { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a mapping override:

```
public class RoleOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Role>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Role> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Capabilities)
               .Cascade.All()
               .Table("RoleCapability")
               .Element("CapabilityId", e => e.Type<NHibernate.Type.EnumType<Capability>>())
               .AsBag()
               .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Here is my filter:

```
public class FilterHasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
          instance.ApplyFilter<TenantFilter>("tenantid = :tid");
    }
}

public class TenantFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public TenantFilter()
    {
        WithName("TenantFilter").AddParameter("tid", NHibernateUtil.String);
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to load my Role object, there is an issue where it is doing this:

```
SELECT capabiliti0_.RoleId as RoleId0_, capabiliti0_.CapabilityId as Capabili2_0_ 
FROM RoleCapability capabiliti0_ WHERE  capabiliti0_.tenantid = :TenantFilter.tid and capabiliti0_.RoleId=?
```

The problem is that TenantId should not be applied to the RoleCapability relationship.  Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
public abstract class TenantEntity
{
public virtual int TenantId {get;set;}

}


public class Role : TenantEntity
{
public virtual int TenantId {get;set;
public virtual IList<Capability> Capabilities { get; set; }
}

public class FilterHasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.ChildType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TenantEntity)))
        {
                instance.ApplyFilter<TenantFilter>("tenantid = :tid");  
        }
    }
}
```